# How to get popular tags from instagram?

Tags: instagram

I want to get most popular tags from [instgram](/questions/tagged/instgram) as http://ink361.com/. 
Perhaps this is not given in the `instagram API`.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: This is not exposed through the Instagram API I'm afraid

Comment: A very similar question was asked after yours but it has an answer already -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138922/how-do-i-get-the-most-popular-tags